# Raw Data Download in Flurry

Tags: flurry

i am trying to use Raw Data Download in Flurry.([link](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/rdd/))

So, i am sending an POST request to raw data api of flurry using Postman.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://rawdata.flurry.com/pulse/v1/rawData \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: **programmtics user token** \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 9df055be-304a-4403-b300-603ec4c21e30' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "data": 
    {
     "type": "rawData",
     "attributes": {
         "startTime": "1537833600000",
         "endTime": "1540425600000",
         "outputFormat": "JSON",
         "apiKey": "app token"
        }
    }
}

'
```

i get this error:

```
{"code":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

i am doing something wrong, what is it?

my programmatic user has the raw data download **enabled**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping

```
-H 'Authorization: **programmtics user token**
```

for

```
-H 'Authorization: Bearer **programmtics user token**
```

Comment: my bad, didn't notice the **Bearer** keyword.